# AlertDialog With View Layout Inside RecyclerView Adapter

Tags: android, mobile, android-recyclerview

How can i get alertDialog with xml layout to work inside recyclerView Adapter?

```
      customViewHolder.decision.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 

{
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        AlertDialog.Builder com = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
                        View mCom = LayoutInflater..........?
                        com.setTitle("Complete");
                        com.create().show();
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
customViewHolder.decision.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    AlertDialog.Builder com = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
                    View mCom = View.inflate(mContext, R.layout.complete_order, null);
                    com.setTitle("Complete");
                    com.create().show();
                }
            });
```

I use this code and its works

Answer (score -1):

```
customViewHolder.decision.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(mContext);
            dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.complete_order);

            dialog.show();

        }
    });
```